# Access a node/path by two specific users only

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I've read up and tried denormalization and while it makes perfect sense for cases like comments/messages that are accessible publicly while a user can only write to his own path/node, I'm having a hard time restricting ".read" rule to the user/owner AND to another user/admin. My use case doesn't publicly post all messages. To expound, for example, messages by user1 are only readable by user1 and admin, while still retaining write-only to user1.

How is this achieved? In security rules, I tried:

```
"messages": {
   ".read": "auth !== null",
   ".write": "auth !== null",
   "$message": {
      ".read": "data.child('userID').val() === auth.uid"
   }
}
```

OR

```
"messages": {
   ".write": "auth !== null",
   "$message": {
      ".read": "data.child('userID').val() === auth.uid"
   }
}
```

OR

```
"messages": {
   "$user_id": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id"
      ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
   }
}
```

While the last one does restrict reading and writing to the authenticated user, say user1, I had no luck getting the admin user to get all users' messages. The first, I can't circumvent the cascading/top-down rule.

I'm a firebase newbie so if this is really simple to do, I appreciate any helping hand.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This depends on how you define an administrator.

Let's first say that your admin is a known user with uid `SOF`.

```
"messages": {
   "$user_id": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id || auth.uid == 'SOF'"
      ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
   }
}
```

If you want the administrator to be configurable, you'll probably store their ID somewhere else, say in a node called `administrators`:

```
administrators
    SOF: true
    Frank: true
messages
    ...
```

In that case your can check if the current uid is either in the current node or it exists in the list of administrators:

```
"messages": {
   "$user_id": {
      ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id || root.child('administrators/'+auth.uid).exists()"
      ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
   }
}
```

### Update

Since you want administrators to be able to read all messages, you'll end up with:

```
"messages": {
  ".read": "root.child('administrators/'+auth.uid).exists()",
  "$user_id": {
    ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id",
    ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank. Thanks for the feedback. But how does the admin user get ALL the users' messages since top node "messages" is not readable? Making "messages" to ".read": true will make it public which is contrary to the goal. Any other tips? Thanks again.

Comment: You can add a similar `.read` rule there just allowing the administrators: `".read": "root.child('administrators/'+auth.uid).exists()"`

Comment: Confirmed that that lets the admin access all messages but now each specific user can no longer access their own node. I understand this is because of the Cascading Security Rules: https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade

Is there any way to "append" permission to top level in the user level?

Comment: Cascading only applies to granted permissions. If a user is denied read privileges on the top messages node, they can still be granted permission on their lower $user_id node.

Comment: Thanks @Anid Monsur. That helped in paving the way for a solution. So I ended up with restructuring the messages nodes and adding these rules:

`code`
"messages": {
      ".read": "root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/roles/administrator').exists()",
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user_id || root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/roles/administrator').exists()",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user_id"
      }
    }`code`

Comment: The check for admin privileges under a specific message is unnecessary, since admins would be granted access on the top level messages node. You should be able to use something similar to what Frank posted under his update.